# Continued minipage geometry

Tags: geometry, layout, definition

I need to motivate certain definition, and to do that I used minipage environment for the motivation part. However when the length of the motivation is more the section doesn't continue to next page but takes the whole section to the next page.

My question is what package/command should I use to get the desired look without going to new page.

My code is the following,

```
\section{Section name}
\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}[t]{.95\textwidth}
\end{minipage}
\end{center}
Ca Ca Do Do
\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}[t]{.95\textwidth}
Pee pee poo poo
\end{minipage}
\end{center}
```

The result I get is the following,

[image]

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You have the `adjustwidth` environment, from  `changepage`.

Comment: the main use of `minipage` is to prevent that section breaking over a page. If I understand your question you just want to remove the `center` and `minipage` but just enlarge the margins with eg `quote` environment

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I like how it looks when I use minipage. I want to change the geometry locally to look like this, by your description minipage is the wrong thing to use. I don't know how ```quote``` works. Does it increase the margin size like minipage is doing in the above example? and leave the page if the whole thing doesn't fit?

Comment: yes that's all it does, basically.

Comment: @Bernard I will check it out!

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you I will check it out. Don't close the question yet, please. :D

Comment: no reason to close the question someone can answer (adjustwidth is basically the same as quote but allows the indent to be parameterinsed and has a less "semantic" name)

Comment: Thank you @Bernard adjust width worked!